# why does the bottom div text bleed into top div

Tags: html, css

Hello I am making a basic portfolio https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GbVwje page and I am having trouble with divs. Currently the bottom div (My Work) is bleeding into the top div (header). How can I get the header to just stack on top of my work with out bleeding? I have been trying everything and I cannot figure out why it is happening.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Roboto Cn", sans-serif;
}

/* body */
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

header {
  background: white;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 100%;
}

/* nav bar */
#logo {
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 55px 0 55px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
nav img {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 51px;
}
nav ul {
  float: right;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

#about {
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 200px 200px 0 200px;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

#work {
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
 <body>
    <header>
      <nav>
        <div id="logo"><img src="/images/logo.png" /></div>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">work</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <p id="about">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
        veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
        commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
        velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
        occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
        mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </header>
    <section id="work">
      <h1>My Work</h1>
      <div class="flex-container">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <div id="contact">
      <h1>Contact</h1>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <h1>Footer</h1>
    </footer>

    <!-- jQuery CDN -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: maybe change your `height: 80vh` on your `header` to `min-height: 80vh`

Answer (score 0):

If you put the “about” text into its own section it stops the bleeding from happening.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do is to change your height on the header element from `height: 80vh;` to `min-height: 80vh;`

```
header {
  background: white;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 80vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

The reason why the text was "bleeding" into the My work section is because the header was not large enough for the content you had in there. This makes the header div 80vh when the screen is wide enough to fit all of your text in there, but allows it to expand if the screen is thinner and forcing the text to wrap more.

Check this snippet for a working demo:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Roboto Cn", sans-serif;
}


/* body */

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

header {
  background: white;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 80vh;
  width: 100%;
}


/* nav bar */

#logo {
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 55px 0 55px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav img {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 51px;
}

nav ul {
  float: right;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

#about {
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 200px 200px 0 200px;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

#work {
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <div id="logo"><img src="/images/logo.png" /></div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <p id="about">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </header>
  <section id="work">
    <h1>My Work</h1>
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>6</div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <div id="contact">
    <h1>Contact</h1>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <h1>Footer</h1>
  </footer>

  <!-- jQuery CDN -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Roboto Cn", sans-serif;
}

/* body */
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

header {
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 50px;
}

/* nav bar */
#logo {
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
nav img {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 51px;
}
nav ul {
  float: right;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

#about {
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px 30px;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

#work {
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px 0;
}
```

```html
 <body>
    <header>
      <nav>
        <div id="logo"><img src="/images/logo.png" /></div>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">work</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <p id="about">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
        veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
        commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
        velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
        occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
        mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </header>
    <section id="work">
      <h1>My Work</h1>
      <div class="flex-container">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <div id="contact">
      <h1>Contact</h1>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <h1>Footer</h1>
    </footer>

    <!-- jQuery CDN -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Instead of using height try to use `padding` on the parent `div`. Hope it'll help